# Angular infinite re-rendering at parent component

Tags: javascript, angular

[Stackblitz to reproduce issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5fqura)

Hello, my Angular7 app consists of a parent component, called `timesheet`, and a child component, called `row`. In this example, I want `timesheet` to generate an `<app-row>` component for each day on a given month, which in this case is May.

Now, `<app-row>` component only consists of a `<td>` element with an `input` field that accepts a number. Nothing too fancy so far.

Timesheet component:

```
<div *ngFor="let week of splitMonthIntoWeeks(getMonthDays(month))">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          Hours:
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr app-row *ngFor="let day of week"></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Row component:

```
<td><input type="number"></td>
```

This works quite fine. However, if I try to link each row component's input element to a property in the model with the `[(ngModel)]` directive, I get an infinite re-rendering of the app (which you can reproduce in the link above. At first it will work fine, you gotta add the `[(ngModel)]` directive to the row component as I'm showing below).

To summarize, this change gives infinite re-rendering:

```
<td><input type="number" [(ngModel)]="hours"></td>
```

Now, I don't really know how Angular manages changes and maybe I'm missing something, so any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See solution here

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cjxqyt

You should not call your functions (`splitMonthIntoWeeks` and `getMonthDays`) directly in the template, because it will be call at each rendering cycle. It means for every call, a new array containing new `Date` will be generated. `ngFor` works by checking if its value is stricly the same object (with `===`) as the last cycle.

If the comparison doesn't match, `ngFor` thinks it's a new object, so it destroy the corresponding DOM element and generate a new one. You can see it by `console.log` in the `RowComponent` component constructor.

When comparing two complexe object, like `Date` it checks if the object is really the same (same pointer in memory), but in your case, its not because the function keeps recreating new one.

So, instead of calling your functions in every cycle, you can create your array and persist the result in a local property and recalculate this array only when the `@Input` `month` changes. To do so, you can use `onChanges` lifecycle, or use a setter for your `@Input` (like in my exemple).

Comment: Thanks!!! Works like a charm. So Angular has some sort of react-styled virtual dom to check what's gonna get updated?

Comment: Not a virtual DOM, Angular only check if its bindings have changed since the last iteration. If it does, Angular re-render this element accordingly. I'm not good enough in english to explain it more clearly :/ You can read some articles about Angular change detector ;)

Comment: Honestly, thanks a lot! No way I could have found that out before going crazy haha.